# How to take a portion screenshot by using QuickTime Player and save it to the clipboard in macOS when using Apple Script for automation?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, screenshot, quicktime

I'm a uni student taking online courses, I take portion screenshots by pressing Command+**Control**+Shift+4 every time to take notes, then I **paste** it to *Notion.* But it's **not efficient** to **select the same area every time,** then I found that **QuickTime Player will keep the same area** for capturing a portion screenshot, so I decided to use Apple Script to complete the operation.

The code I wrote could switch to the application *QuickTime Player* and then proceed to "New Screen Recording" in the menu by pressing Command+Control+N, but the problem is that **sometimes pressing twice space will call out "Capture Selected Window" instead of "Capture Selected Portion".** Meanwhile, the location where saving the screenshots will also be changed too though I already ticked "Remember Last Selection", maybe resetting the location to be saved every time is essential.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    activate application "QuickTime Player"
    
    tell application "System Events"
        
        key code 45 using {command down, control down}
        delay 0.1
        
        # Switch to "Capture Select Portion" by pressing SPACE
        repeat 2 times
            key code 49
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        
        # Press ENTER to capture a screenshot
        key code 35
        delay 0.1
        
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```

I spent a few hours finding the **existed articles** but **perhaps not that fulfill my needs.**

`do shell script "screencapture -ci"` is as same as pressing Command+Control+Shift+4, and I **have to select the portion manually.**

`do shell script "screencapture -x -R20,20,640,380 ~/Desktop/test.png"` **needs a precise coordinate.** But the coordinate is variable since the window is not fixed, and it needs to be found by using external software, maybe it's a little bit not efficient. **If there is no solution for that, I will use it** since it's much more convenient than selecting the portion every time.

Sorry about pasting others' code here and saying why they r not suitable for me, I just wanted to make it clear... Thanks for reading here, **have a nice day** no matter if u r willing to help me ^ ^

The part about pasting screenshots to *Notion* works, so I didn't paste it here.

[image: Save to Clipboard instead of Preview]

Comment: Your `screencapture` using the 'R' coordinates works for me (I'm running Sierra). I gather that you need to change those coordinates? What do you base them upon? It is easy enough to feed a different set of coordinates: e.g. `"screencapture -R" & "40,40,840,640"`. Of course, you can set a variable to string of coordinates as well.

Comment: On another note, there is (or used to be) a paid app called 'Clarify', published by 'Blue Mango' which is useful for grabbing sections of the screen in an orderly fashion. I used to use it to capture our training tests, documentation and whatall, and found it very useful. I last used v2.

Answer (score 1):

I tried writing something, **it works but still has some bugs.**

For example, **the coordinate** of the menu "Options" should **be initialized depending on the precise location of the bar** since I didn't succeed in finding the element by using `entire contents`.

You **can't move your mouse during the use,** or it might cause an error:

`System Events got an error: Can’t get menu \"Options\" of button \"Options\" of window \"Window\" of application process \"screencaptureui\"." number -1728 from menu "Options" of button "Options" of window "Window" of application process "screencaptureui`

When selecting the path where screenshots will be saved, it might **take a few seconds** to let the program find the menu item **Clipboard**.

```
tell application "System Events"
    
    tell process "QuickTime Player"
        
        # Switch to QuickTime Player (already opened expected, no launching time reserved)
        activate
        
        # Open "New Screen Recording" from the menu
        click menu item "New Screen Recording" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "QuickTime Player" of application "System Events"
        
        delay 1
        
    end tell
    
    # Capture Selected Portion
    tell application process "screencaptureui"
        
        click checkbox "Capture Selected Portion" of window "Window" of application process "screencaptureui" of application "System Events"
        
        # Select Options from the menu (idk why if I replace it with click menu, the clipboard won't be found, needs to be fixed)
        click at {817, 824}
        delay 0.1
        
        # Save to the Clipboard
        click menu item "Clipboard" of menu "Options" of button "Options" of window "Window" of application process "screencaptureui" of application "System Events"
        delay 1
        
    end tell
    
    # Enter to capture the screenshot
    key code 36
    delay 0.1
    
    # Switch to Notion (already opened expected, no launching time reserved)
    tell application "Notion"
        activate
        
        delay 0.1
        
    end tell
    
    # Paste the screenshot to Notion
    key code 9 using {command down}
    
end tell
```

Hope this helps someone, if u hv any idea plz feel free to modify it since it still has bugs.